# Can not access submenu element with UIA backend

Tags: pywinauto

I am using the latest pywinauto code from github as of 2019/07/04.

I am trying to access an Eclipse based application menu/submenu entry.  The code I am using to do this is:

```
mainwinobj.menu_select("Project->My first menu->my second menu(specific)")
```

Unfortunately, this raises an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <MYPATH>\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py", line 1073, in item_by_path
    menu = next_level_menu(menu, menu_items[i], items_cnt == i + 1)
  File "<MYPATH>\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py", line 1053, in next_level_menu
    return self._sub_item_by_text(parent_menu, item_name, exact, is_last)
  File "<MYPATH>\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py", line 1017, in _sub_item_by_text
    self._activate(sub_item, is_last)
  File "<MYPATH>\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py", line 984, in _activate
    if not item.is_active():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

Nevertheless, I can see that it correctly clicked on `My first menu` but it did not on the second one.

**I am also getting an inconsistent behavior**, sometimes I can see that it mistakenly clicks on the submenu located graphically above `My first menu` after having clicked correctly on `My first menu`, leading to the correct submenu disappears from the screen.  It does not change that the exception stills occurs, but it impacts the workarounds I tried as described below.

**root causing the issue**

I was quickly able to understand the root cause of the issue: in `_sub_item_by_text`, the line

```
items = menu.items()
```

returns an empty list and therefore the `sub_item` remains None.

**tried solutions**

I tried many different things around a core solution that sometimes lead to a correct behavior, but it is never consistent.  Basically, I force searching the windows to try to find a Menu:

```
        if not menu.items():
            print("waiting for menu " + menu.window_text())
            time.sleep(1)
            menus = menu.top_level_parent().children(control_type="Menu", title=menu.window_text())
            print(menus)
            menu = menus[0]
```

or other solution like:

```
        if not menu.items():
            print("waiting for menu " + menu.window_text())
            self._activate(menu, False)
            timings.wait_until(
                timings.Timings.window_find_timeout,
                timings.Timings.window_find_retry,
                lambda: len(self.top_level_parent().descendants(control_type="Menu", title=menu.window_text())) > 0)
            menus = menu.top_level_parent().children(control_type="Menu", title=menu.window_text())
            print(menus)
            menu = menus[0]
```

or I removed the activate:

```
        if not menu.items():
            print("waiting for menu " + menu.window_text())
            timings.wait_until(
                timings.Timings.window_find_timeout,
                timings.Timings.window_find_retry,
                lambda: len(self.top_level_parent().descendants(control_type="Menu", title=menu.window_text())) > 0)
            menus = menu.top_level_parent().children(control_type="Menu", title=menu.window_text())
            print(menus)
            menu = menus[0]
```

But in the end, nothing of this worked consistently, it sometimes does, but when I get this extra click on the submenu entry above the one I am expecting, it always fails because it makes the correct menu disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem, the problem was due to the fact that, before calling `menu_select`,  the mouse pointer was located at a position that was conflicting with the submenu graphical expansion.

For some reason, before selecting the last submenu entry, the system was 'clicking' where the mouse was located, ended up being at a different menu entry.

Therefore, in order to avoid this issue, I forced the pointer to a location on which there was no possible action before invoking the menu_select.

In a second step, I used the win32 as a backend for the automation of most of the elements that I had to manipulate (safer, better supported) and I used UIA only for complex elements.